# R choose which element of factor variable to throw out to produce only positive coefficients

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

How to manually choose which element of factor variable to throw out? Or how to automatically throw out the element with the least coefficient so that in the final model we have all the coefficients of factor variables > 0.

```
y <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4)
x <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue")
dataset <- data.frame(y, x)

model <- lm(y ~ x, data=dataset)
summary(model)
```

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   3.0000     0.4714   6.364  0.00313 **
xred         -1.6667     0.6667  -2.500  0.06677 .    -- here this xred coefficient is negative
```

If instead xblue was chosen the coefficient would be positive. How to do it?

Throwing out the intercept from the model is not a solution because in case of multiple categorical variables problem will be solved for only one variable.

Edit. This jugglery might be good for aesthetics and storytelling. Suppose "colors" are different types of promotion and we are to interpret the model parameters to marketing stuff. Marketing people will feel much better seeing only positive coefficients for their variable. Explaining negative coefficients for stimulant variables is unnecessary challenge.

Comment: But why do you want to do this? It sounds misinformed, but maybe you have some very specific reason. Then you need to state that!

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure why you would want to do this but what you are referring to is simply changing the reference group. You can do that with the *relevel* function

```
y <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4)
x <- c("red", "blue", "red", "blue", "red", "blue")
dataset <- data.frame(y, x)

######## RELEVEL ###############
dataset$x = relevel(dataset$x, ref = 'red')
################################

model <- lm(y ~ x, data=dataset)
summary(model)

    Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   1.3333     0.4714   2.828   0.0474 *
xblue         1.6667     0.6667   2.500   0.0668 .
```

Comment: The function relevel answers how to do it manually. Great! Is there a way to impose that color coefficient should be >0 so that automatically the color with the least coefficient is thrown out? Why? Imagine that the colors are types of promotion, and by chance R chose the color with the highest coefficient as a reference. And you are to explain marketing people that all the types of promotion produce negative effect on sales...

Comment: I believe this has been solved in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21257/how-can-factor-levels-be-automatically-chosen-in-r-to-maximize-the-number-of-pos)

Comment: +1 for finding the duplicate.